# Slider not displaying images but plain text

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use a slider in different blog pages in a Wordpress website, but it doesn't work. When I use it, it only shows plain text: [metaslider id=4281]

It seems that "blog entries" don't understand the Metaslider code, because I have tried in a simple page, and it works. Here's the code of a blog entry (single.php)

```
    <?php get_header()?>
    <div id="maincontent">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); //The Loop?>
        <div <?php post_class()?>>

<?php if(has_tag()){the_tags( _e('Keywords','polaroids') . ': ', ', ');}?><br/>

<hr style="border: 0;border-bottom: 1px dashed #DDDDDD;"></br>

            <h1><?php the_title()?></h1>


             <div class="date"><?php /* the_date() */ ?></div>

             <div class="post-content"><? echo $post->post_content; /*php the_content()*/ ?></div> 

             <div class="postfooter">
             <?php wp_link_pages('before=Pages&after='); ?><br/>


             </div>

<hr style="border: 0;border-bottom: 1px dashed #DDDDDD;">
<div class="breadcrumbs"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
<hr style="border: 0;border-bottom: 1px dashed #DDDDDD;">


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I suspect that echoing the post_content might be returning the plain text. Not sure why the_content is commented out but try using that.

So instead of this:

`<? echo $post->post_content; /*php the_content()*/ ?></div>`

Try using this:

`<?php the_content(); ?>`